# Import overrides.scss from parent theme

Tags: shopware6

What is the best way to import overrides.scss from a parent theme in theme.json?

```
  "app/storefront/src/scss/overrides.scss",
  "@ParentTheme",
  "@ChildTheme",
  "app/storefront/src/scss/base.scss"
],
```

Can't figure out the best way, I now have this in my ChildTheme overrides.scss but that seems a bit ugly:

```
@import '../../../../../../../ParentTheme/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/scss/overrides.scss';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `overrides.scss` file is probably already imported by your parents `theme.json`, so there is no need to include it again in your version.